# "Deform" metal in a thread-forming animation

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I'm a Blender noob, hoping to use the tool to animate the type of fluid deformation that occurs when a tapping tool forms threads into metal.

I've found this [inspirational video](https://youtu.be/yxt9W21YX0w?t=27) that closely replicates what I hope to achieve. Can you provide suggestions for how I might accomplish a similar look in Blender?

Comment: You will want to look after Shape Key Animation